# NUnit: XSLT to transform NUnit output to MSBuild errors and warnings format

Tags: xslt, msbuild, nunit

I want my NUnit output transformed into msbuild error format so I can report on these in the Visual Studio error list. I know TestDriven.Net does the same.

**MSBuild error format samples:**

Main.cs(17,20): warning CS0168: The variable 'foo' is declared but never used 
C:\dir1\foo.resx(2) : error BC30188: Declaration expected.
cl : Command line warning D4024 : unrecognized source file type 'foo.cs', object file assumed
error CS0006: Metadata file 'System.dll' could not be found.

**Post by MSBuild team blog on this format:**

http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2006/11/03/msbuild-visual-studio-aware-error-messages-and-message-formats.aspx

Comment: I don't see any question at all. What is it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of NUnit output? Is this XML at all? Why do you think people are supposed to know what NUnit is?

Comment: Please add a sample of your NUnit output.