# Run and publish xUnit.net tests in a TFS 2008 build

Tags: xslt, msbuild, mstest, tfsbuild, xunit.net

I have team build running on a TFS 2008 server. I want it to run my xUnit.net tests there and show the result in the Build details.

I know I have to do a lot of configuration in the TFSBuild.proj script file. I already managed to make the tests run, but the result does not appear in the build. I followed the instructions from [mehfuz's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/mehfuzh/archive/2009/08/25/configuring-team-build-using-xunit.aspx).

Looking at other similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517560/how-do-i-get-team-build-to-show-test-results-and-coverage-for-xunit-net-test-suit), I got to [Jonne Kats' post](http://jonnekats.wordpress.com/2009/05/07/integrate-xunit-tests-into-your-daily-team-build/). Unfortunately, it's kind of obsolete. There's a lot a workaround included to overcome the lack of an ExitCode in the xunit task. With xunit 1.7, this is not required anymore.

I'm having a hard time trying to set this up. Can someone show me a way to publish the test results into the team build?

---

**Update:** I see that my question actually consists of a lot of small questions. Let me make it more direct.

I'm running an [Xunit.Runner.MSBuild.xunit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=HowToUseMSBuild) task successfully. It is set to generate a XML file with a test report. In order to show this report in the TFS Build Details, I need to import it using [MSTest.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243151.aspx). However, I must first convert it to a format that MSTest will understand.

Does anyone has a XSLT file that I could use for transforming the xUnit XML report into a MSTest TRX file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NUnit: XSLT to transform NUnit output to MSBuild errors and warnings format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721254/nunit-xslt-to-transform-nunit-output-to-msbuild-errors-and-warnings-format)

Comment: user357812: It's related, but not a duplicate: this question is about XUnit, not NUnit.

Comment: jpbochi: have you found a solution?

Comment: @ghostskunks: If I remember correctly, I built my own TFS task to solve the problem. Unfortunately, I'm working on a different place now and I don't have access to the code anymore. PS.: Sorry for the extremely late response, I don't think I received any alerts for it.

Answer (score 0):

A very promising article is posted here: http://salvoz.com/blog/2010/02/22/transform-xunit-to-mstest/

Unfortunately, the XSLT has been mangled a bit by the blog engine, and I haven't put in the effort to get it working yet.